# Javascript: edit an images height in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to edit an images height that is repeating in a for loop in javascript but I can't figure out where I would need to add it in.

Here are the variables if it's important:

```
        var i;
        var start = 1;
        var seg = document.getElementById("selSegs").value;
        var parent = document.getElementById("divInch"), //parent for appendChild 
                imagePath = 'InchwormSegment.gif', //variable for image
                img; //adding img element
```

Here is my loop:

```
for(i = start; i<=seg; i++) {

            img = new Image(); //creating new image object
            img.src = imagePath; // element src = imagePath
            img.style.height = "215px"; // sets the height of all in loop
            // img.style.height = (img.style.height * .9) + "px"; - does nothing
            parent.appendChild(img); //appendChild adds another child (img) object
        }
```

I've tried adding in some math but I just can't figure out where it is supposed to go

Comment: Are you trying to reduce or increase the image's height on each iteration? Because right now the image height is going to stay at 215px

Comment: @samrap I'm trying to reduce the image's height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this fiddle accomplishes what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/AyNY5/. A few things to remember:

1. You can edit the image "height" attribute directly, no need to go through style (You don't even need to add px!)
2. Don't use new Image() - use document.createElement('img'). That's the W3C supported standard.

If I'm off let me know - otherwise, you were on the right track!

JS Code in Fiddle:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("imgholder")

for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "http://bit.ly/1975WKA"
    img.height = "200"
    parent.appendChild(img)
}
```

Comment: This works but I guess I somehow forgot that each segment after the first has to be 90% of the previous one. I figured if I did x = x * .9 that it'd work, but instead nothing comes up.

Here's a jsfiddle of something I tried but it didn't work because it's not multiply the height itself, but the number of images:

http://jsfiddle.net/jATk4/

Comment: I see. Perhaps this more along the lines of what you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/AyNY5/3/. I see the imgHeight variable outside of the scope of the For loop,  then apply .9 per iteration. It's not quite as clean as it could be, but hope it helps!

Comment: yup!! thanks for the help, I guess I was just over complicating it because I've done that in the past, just had my script all over the place and missed the ordering.

Comment: No worries! If it helped you out, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

At this point image does not have `style.height` assigned. It does have `height` attribute though.

Instead of

```
img.style.height = (img.style.height * .9) + "px";
```

try

```
img.style.height = (img.height * .9) + "px";
```